# Open Computer path in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder

Is there any way to open Computer path in Cocoa? In OSX, if pressing Shift+Command +C , it will open Computer path in Finder. Now i want to open it in Cocoa app. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is run an AppleScript (not difficult with the NSAppleScript class):

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    make new Finder window with properties {target:computer container}
end tell
```